# How to recolor the chapter numbering and text in memoir?

Tags: color, memoir, chapters

I'd like to use the default chapter style in `memoir`, but change the color to, say, blue. How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three `memoir` commands in question are:

```
\chapnamefont
\chapnumfont
\chaptitlefont
```

which, in the default settings, are set to `\Huge` and `\bfseries`. Thus it is a simple matter to redefine them:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}% lipsum.sty is just for this example
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\Huge\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum
\section{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a `\color{blue}` expression after `\chapterheadstart` and revert back to `\color{blue}` at `\memendofchapterhook`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\chapterheadstart{\color{blue}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\memendofchapterhook}{\color{black}}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```